Work required to fill spherical tank at height
Suppose we have a spherical water tank $24$ feet in diameter, sitting atop a $60$ foot tower. The tank is filled by a hose attached to the bottom of the sphere. How long does it take a $1.5$ horsepower pump (one horsepower = $550$ ft-lb of work per second) to fill the tank?
One needs to calculate the work required to fill the tank on top of a $60$ foot tower with a pump on the ground.

Now centering the origin at the center of the sphere, we obtain that the radius $r$ of a circular cross-section is given by $r=x=\sqrt{12^2-y^2}$, and hence its area at sample point $y_i^{*}$ on the $i$-th subinterval $[y_i,y_{i+1}]$ of length $\Delta y$ is $$A_i=\pi\left(\sqrt{12^2-(y_i^*)^2}\right)^2=\pi(12^2-(y_i^*)^2)$$ and volume of the cylindrical slab centered at $y_i^*$ with height $\Delta y$ is $$V_i=\pi (12^2-(y_i^*)^2)\space\Delta y$$
Now since this volume is in cubic feet, and because water weighs $62.5$ lb/ft$^3$, we see that the force required to overcome the weight of this slab of water is $$F_i=62.5 \pi (12^2-(y_i^*)^2)\space\Delta y $$
Finally, the work in pumping the tank full of water is the sum of pumping the volume of each layer (or slab) of water at height $y_i^*$ in the tank by moving it up $60+12+y_i^*$ feet. Thus the distance each slab moves is $$d_i=y_i^*+72$$
So the work $W\approx\sum (F_i\cdot d_i)$ done is given by $$W=\int_{-12}^{12} 62.5\pi(144-y^2)(y+72)dy=3.2572 \times 10^7 \text{ ft-lb}$$
per WA. However, multiple sources indicate this work is actually $5.4287\times 10^6$ ft-lb even though my method and integral is similar to those mentioned in the answers and their comments here.
Where did I go wrong?

The water in the tank weighs about $4.5 \times 10^5$ pounds. If you just lifted the whole tank, sitting in a pit in the ground that's 12 feet deep, so that the center of mass of the tank is at height 0, and moved it up 72 feet, so that it's as it appears in your diagram, you'd have done $72 \times 4.5 \times 10^7$ ft-lbf.  That's very roughly $3\times 10^7$ ft-lbf. So I totally believe your answer, and not the one you found elsewhere.
Why? Because the work needed to move the COM of that water up 72 feet is independent of the path you followed, unless you do something stupid like use a hole to fill the already-raised tank from the top, wasting some of the the energy of the water as it falls down into the raised tank.
The ratio of your answer to the "other folks'" answer is $6$, suggesting some kind of arithmetic error somewhere rather than "I forgot to include 32 ft/sec^2 somewhere" or something like that. In short, I think I like your answer better here.
No...wait! The question isn't "how many ft-lbf are needed?" but instead "How long does it take?". SO you need to divide by 550 to get the number of seconds. I divided by 60 to get the number of minutes, which is about 987 minutes.
But I do agree with you about the amount of work.
